# Link the third party website and Automate the process in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

This is Arun from Chennai. I m going to start a new project in ASP.NET. I need the basic 
idea how to implement the project.

There is a insurance website URL - https://www.unitedhealthcareonline.com/. We have the 
username & password to login for checking the eligibility & claim status for the patients. 
What we are doing right now is, login into the website, checking claim status for each 
patient by giving the necessary fields manually.

We need to automate the process such as if we upload the necessary field information thru 
excel and asp application will process & get the claim status and provide the output.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for:
http://blog.donnfelker.com/2007/09/13/automated-form-posting-with-net-asp-nets-curl/
using asp.net to submit a form on a website without a browser?